# Dynamic report size in Jasper report

Tags: dynamic, size, jasper-reports, report, jasperserver

I need to have my report resize depends on the size of the browser.
Is this possible in Jasperserver 3.7.0.1?

Thanks,
mauleous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Of course reports expand vertically. You didn't specify, but surely you are talking about expanding the width horizontally. JR doesn't handle that easily; JasperReports Server gives you no way to do it.